# How to return primary key as a response after posting data in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In response, I am getting only the readable fields of the posted data. I want to return primary key and username as well.

serializers.py:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'email','password',)
        extra_kwargs = {
                    'password': 
                        {
                         'write_only': True,
                         'required': False
                         }
                    }
        read_only_fields = ('username',)
```

views.py:

```
class UserCreate(UserMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            User.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
            email = serializer.validated_data.get('email', None)
            password = serializer.validated_data.get('password', None)
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I think it might be helpful to see your `UserCreateSerializer` code as that's going to tell the service what to return.

Comment: Updated the code. Sorry for not mentioning before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. You want to save the user before you return, because PK is generated on save. Also you want to serialize the user object, not return the POST data. So at the end of your create() you want something like

```
...
user.save()
response_data = UserCreateSerializer(user).data
return Response(response_data, status...
```

That said, are you sure that you want to automatically login the freshly created user. Seems weird.

Comment: For automatically login, I don't see any issue as sites like FB and twitter also do the same. Verification of email will be required before posting anything.

Answer (score 0):

`User.objects.create_user()`

returns an instance of the user model. you want to use it like that to get the primary key:

```
    user = User.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
    user.save()
    pk = user.pk
```

You need to call save() by yourself to tell django that it should persist now, otherwise this will be done later.

have a look at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) for further information.